# Is there any built in function in numpy to take moving skewness?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

In numpy is there any built-in function to calculate moving skewness of numpy array? I know there are basic functions like `mean`, `median`, `mode`, `min`, `max` etc. But I wonder if there are any functions for calculating moving skewness, kurtosis and higher moments?

Comment: take a look at [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already got solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57146360/8774724). There is no built-in function in `numpy` but we can use `scipy` and `numpy` combine to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SciPy for calculating skewness, kurtosis, etc.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html

Comment: I know already about scipy but I was wondering if it is possible with any numpy function?