# How to calculate moving / running / rolling arbitrary function (e.g. kurtosis & skewness) using NumPy / SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I am working on the time-series data. To get features from data I have to calculate moving mean, median, mode, slop, kurtosis, skewness etc. I am familiar with `scipy.stat` which provides an easy way to calculate these quantities for straight calculation. But for the moving/running part, I have explored the whole internet and got nothing.

Surprisingly moving mean, median and mode are very easy to calculate with `numpy`. Unfortunately, there is no built-in function for calculating kurtosis and skewness.
If someone can help, how to calculate moving kurtosis and skewness with scipy? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) offers a [`DataFrame.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#pandas-dataframe-rolling) method which can be used, in combination with its [`Rolling.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply) method (i.e. `df.rolling().apply()`) to apply an arbitrary function to the specified rolling window.

---

If you are looking for NumPy-based solution, you could use [FlyingCircus Numeric](https://pypi.org/project/flyingcircus-numeric/) (disclaimer: I am the main author of it).

There, you could find the following:

1. `flyingcircus_numeric.running_apply()`: can apply any function to a 1D array and supports weights, but it is slow;
2. `flyingcircus_numeric.moving_apply()`: can apply any function supporting a `axis: int` parameter to a 1D array and supports weights, and it is fast (but memory-hungry);
3. `flyingcircus_numeric.rolling_apply_nd()`: can apply any function supporting a `axis: int|Sequence[int]` parameter to any ND array and it is fast (and memory-efficient), but it does not support weights.

Based on your requirements, I would suggest to use `rolling_apply_nd()`, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import flyingcircus_numeric as fcn

import scipy.stats


NUM = 30
arr = np.arange(NUM)

window = 4
new_arr = fcn.rolling_apply_nd(arr, window, func=sp.stats.kurtosis)
print(new_arr)
# [-1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36
#  -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36 -1.36
#  -1.36 -1.36 -1.36]
```

Of course, feel free to inspect the [source code](https://github.com/norok2/flyingcircus_numeric), it is open source (GPL).

---

## EDIT

Just to get a feeling of the kind of speed we are talking about, these are the benchmarks for the solutions implemented in FlyingCircus:

[image: benchmark]
[image: benchmark_zoom]

The general approach `flyingcircus_numeric.running_apply()` is a couple of orders of magnitude slower than either `flyingcircus_numeric.rolling_apply_nd()` or `flyingcircus_numeric.moving_apply()`, with the first being approx. one order of magnitude faster than the second.
This shows the speed price for generality or support for *weighting*.

The above plots were obtained using the scripts from [here](https://github.com/norok2/BenchmarkTemplateIPY) and the following code:

```
import scipy as sp
import flyingcircus_numeric as fcn 
import scipy.stats


WINDOW = 4
FUNC = sp.stats.kurtosis


def my_rolling_apply_nd(arr, window=WINDOW, func=FUNC):
    return fcn.rolling_apply_nd(arr, window, func=FUNC)


def my_moving_apply(arr, window=WINDOW, func=FUNC):
    return fcn.moving_apply(arr, window, func)


def my_running_apply(arr, window=WINDOW, func=FUNC):
    return fcn.running_apply(arr, window, func)


def equal_output(a, b):
    return np.all(np.isclose(a, b))


input_sizes = (5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000)
funcs = my_rolling_apply_nd, my_moving_apply, my_running_apply

runtimes, input_sizes, labels, results = benchmark(
    funcs, gen_input=np.random.random, equal_output=equal_output,
    input_sizes=input_sizes)

plot_benchmarks(runtimes, input_sizes, labels, units='s')
plot_benchmarks(runtimes, input_sizes, labels, units='ms', zoom_fastest=8)
```

---

(EDITED to reflect some refactoring of [FlyingCircus](https://pypi.org/project/flyingcircus/))

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and effort. Actually, my requirements was to use only `numpy` and `scipy`. I was aware of pandas `df.rolling().apply()` but was out of the scope of the project. I will definitely look [FlyingCircus](https://pypi.org/project/flyingcircus/). Luckily I have managed to get the job done with simple `numpy` and `scipy`. Please have a look at my answer.  Many thanks!

Comment: @KhurramKhalil Your answer implements something similar to `flyingcircus.extra.running_apply()`. Timewise, this is not an ideal solution in your case, as you can see from the benchmarks I have added to my *EDIT*.

Comment: thanks again for your kind efforts. I have got your point, actually I needed solution for just few thousand entries of data, so i quickly deployed what was managed. However, I am shifting to `flyingcircus.extra.rolling_apply_nd()` for future use.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around, I have come up with a solution that is purely `numpy` and `scipy` based. Of course it is using [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#statistical-functions-scipy-stats) `kurtosis` and `skew`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kurtosis, skew

# Window size
N = 4

# Some random data
m = np.array([2, 3, 10, 11, 0, 4, 8, 2, 5, 9])

# Running Kurtosis
def runningKurt(x, N):
    # Initilize placeholder array
    y = np.zeros((len(x) - (N - 1),))
    for i in range(len(x) - (N - 1)):

         y[i] = kurtosis(x[i:(i + N)])

    return y

# Running Kurtosis

def runningSkew(x, N):
    # Initilize placeholder array
    y = np.zeros((len(x) - (N - 1),))
    for i in range(len(x) - (N - 1)):

         y[i] = skew(x[i:(i + N)])

    return y

kurt = runningKurt(m, N)
print("kurtosis : ", kurt)
# kurtosis :  [-1.93940828 -1.77879935 -1.61464214 -1.40236694 -1.15428571 -1.07626667 -1.42666667]


skw = runningSkew(m, N)
print("skew : ", skw)
# skew :  [ 0.         -0.1354179  -0.26356495 -0.13814702  0.43465076  0.32331615 -0.36514837]
```

Comment: This is essentially the approach taken in `flyingcircus.extra.running_apply()` which is horribly slow, check out the update to my answer to have a feeling of how much slower this is compared to `flyingcircus.extra.rolling_apply_nd()`. Basically the problem is that you are using an explicit loop, which is typically not the fastest way of processing NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @KhurramKhalil I would suggest a solution using list comprehension to avoid the `for` loop:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kurtosis, skew

x = [1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 81, 25, 35, 1, 6]

def calculate_rolling_skewness(array_series: np.ndarray, window: int) -> np.ndarray:
    # According to the series size, set the calculable windows
    positions_to_be_calculated = len(array_series) - (window - 1)

    # Kurtosis calculation for each window
    skewness_series = [skew(array_series[i:(i + window)]) for i in range(positions_to_be_calculated)]

    # Concatenate the series to have the same initial array size
    skewness_series = np.concatenate((np.full(window-1, np.nan), skewness_series), axis=0)

    return skewness_series

 

calculate_rolling_skewness(array_series=x, window=window)
```

Results:

```py
array([        nan,         nan,  0.38180177,  0.38180177, -0.59517006,
        0.70665284,  0.56731658,  0.61897406, -0.45563859,  0.6485518 ])
```

You can do the same using the `kurtosis` function as well.